# Recursive count of a char in Str -- Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

guys
I'm having some problems with something really basic. I have a suggested solution to a problem that looks like (below) but I don't understand how the static argument of countX == str.substring(1) is supposed to search the entire String, the argument is a static 1 (?!?!) :

```
   public int countX(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) return 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
    return countX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Instead I thought of this solution before looking up for the solution but can't figure out how to identify the right most char of the substring for comparison with the searched char 'x' (line : 3)

```
 public int countX(String str) {
  if (str.length()>0) {
    if (str.charAt(str.substring(str.length()-1) == 'x'))
      return countX (str.substring(str.length()-1)) + 1;
    else
      return countX (str.substring(str.length() -1)
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion for my ignorance about the first solution and my mistake on the second ?Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the docs for `substring`?

Comment: yeah and couldn't find a way to define what I call String.substring.length ()

Comment: `substring(1)` will return the `String` minus the first char. So if you do `"abcd".substring(1);` it will return `"bcd"`

Comment: got that but what I can't understand is why the subsequent recursive call let's say of abcd.substring(1); call "cd" this time. Should I just take it as it is  (it's the way substring works) ?

Comment: On every recursive call, you will pass the `String` minus the first character. You check if the first character is an x, and if so up the count.

Comment: Think of it like cutting a log. Everytime, you cut off a part of the log and slide it down. Then you cut off another part and slide it down. Just because the size of the pieces you cut off are a constant one foot, doesn't mean you won't reach the end of the log

Comment: owwwww just realized that the recursive call is done on already a substring after the first time so that's why it keeps chopping off the string. Thanks your analogy just started the right thought chain :))

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the first solution. The idea is to split the string into its first character and the rest.

- If the first character is an x we have to add 1 to the count and continue recursively.
- If it is not an x we have to add nothing and continue recursively.
- For the rest: let us split this up again into its first character and its rest (aka recursion)

To catch also the situation of an empty string, the length of the input is checked first. If length is 0, then the count of x is zero.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what I couldn't get is how can the recursion continue if the argument of substring in the recursive call countX(str.substring(1)) [line 3] is always 1, shouldn't the whole thing go into stackOverflow and explode leaving corpses everywhere ?

Comment: No, this one takes the 2nd character until end of string to the next recursion level. With each level the string to examine is one character shorter.